.NET 6.0 application fails to use COM object on Windows Server 2018
I developed a Windows Service application in .NET Framework 4.8 that manages a process queue. During execution, the service launches another process that internally calls a COM Object using Activator.CreateInstance(type). If permissions are not set up correctly, I get the following error during the function call in the launched process:
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {88FAF7D3-0C9D-4FFE-BD48-794D1E43DD52} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).

Configuration That Works on Windows 10/11
I already opened a topic on the question to solve the problem in the past here: .NET 6.0 application fails to use COM object when launched from Windows service after user logs out.
After some trial and error, I discovered a working solution on Windows 10/11:

In Services, under the properties of my service -> Log On tab -> Select
a local user account (USER).
In Component Services (dcomcnfg) → DCOM
Config → Properties for the COM Object (CLSID
{88FAF7D3-0C9D-4FFE-BD48-794D1E43DD52}):


General tab: Set Authentication Level to None.
Identity tab: Select "The following user" and specify credentials for USER.
Security tab: Customize permissions: Add USER and grant Local Launch/Activation, Remote Launch/Activation, and Full Control.

With this setup, the process launched by the service communicates with the COM object without issues.
Issue on Windows Server 2018
My customer production server uses Windows Server 2018. Applying the same configuration does not work, and the "Retrieving the COM class factory" error appears again.
Additionally, the System Event Viewer logs the following error:
The server {88FAF7D3-0C9D-4FFE-BD48-794D1E43DD52} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.

When I change the COM Object's Identity to "Interactive User," the process works without errors. This suggests a permissions issue with USER on the server.
Question
What could be the configuration differences between Windows 10/11 and Windows Server 2018 that are causing this permission issue?
Are there additional policies or security configurations on Windows Server 2018 that might restrict DCOM or COM object access?
What other settings should I verify or adjust to allow USER to properly access and instantiate the COM object?
Any advice or insight is greatly appreciated!

The following may be of interest: KB5019966, Windows Update Catalog KB5019966, and Setting Security for COM Applications

There can be tons of differences between a Windows setup and another (event with same version, client or server). Relatively recently, Microsoft has hardened DCOM auth, make sure you read, understand and assess that with your customer  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/blog/windows-itpro-blog/dcom-authentication-hardening-what-you-need-to-know/3657154 however you should get related messages in event viewer
